# Regex test returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I'm out of ideas for fixing this issue... this regex which is fine by https://regex101.com/ keeps returning false.

What am I missing?

```
   function validateName(firstname) {
    var re = /^[A - Za - z]{2,2}[ \-_A - Za - z] * $/;
    return re.test(firstname);
}

if (!validateName($('#firstname').val())) {
            errors.push('firstname');
        }
```

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Remove the spaces from the pattern. You did not test *that* regex at regex101.com, I am sure.

Comment: Well I did... apprently regex101 deletes spaces, missed it /:

Comment: That is not true, it does not remove any spaces - https://regex101.com/r/GNFQLD/1. More, you can see that space, `-`, space in the character class creates a range that only matches a space.

Comment: You are right, apprently Visual Studio makes those spaces... funny how you are 100% sure I failed on purpose...  it did solved my problem so thanks.

Comment: I am sure the problem is caused by a typo, and it does not matter much what caused the typo. The post should be closed as off-topic.

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2105 Pro, and it does not meddle with the content I am pasting there. Really, I have no idea what you did to make these spaces appear.

Comment: lol, Im using Visual 2017 and it does.... no idea why. won't fall for this again. we can keep on with our lives . much appriciate for your help!

Comment: Ok, I will install the new version and check.

Comment: Same thing occurred to me today with  VS2015 Pro. Let's live and learn.

Answer (score 0):

A regex could look like this

```
/^[A-Za-z]{2}[\-_A-Za-z]*$/
```

And the false/ true is based on the test cases.

This will return true for Te , Test_ , teSt- , test and etc.

And return false for abc123, a , t,

```js
var re=/^[A-Za-z]{2,2}[\-_A-Za-z]*$/;
console.log(re.test('tE_'));
console.log(re.test('Te'));
console.log(re.test('tE-'));
console.log(re.test('test'));
```

Comment: ty mate, the issues were the spaces which visual studio is automatically doing. good day